# Error while downloading "highcharter" package in r

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to download "highcharter" but got the error below. I also tried installing "rjson" but I got "package ‘rjson’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)" message

```
ERROR: dependency 'rjson' is not available for package 'highcharter'
* removing 'C:/Users/elif.gencaslan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/highcharter'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘highcharter’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: install `rjson` package

Comment: I tried but "package ‘rjson’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)" got this message

Comment: Install old version of `rjson`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem: Outdated R version

The latest version of `rjson` (0.2.21) depends on R version >= 4.0.0 (see [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html)), and it seems like you have R version 3.6.3.

#### Best solution: Update R

Your best option is to update your version of R before installing `rjson` or `highcharter`.

#### Alternatives: Install old version of `rjson`

An alternative is to install an older version of `rjson` (0.2.20 should work with your version of R).

You can either do this with packages like `renv`:

```r
renv::install("rjson@0.2.20")
```

Or `remotes`:

```r
remotes::install_version("rjson", "0.2.20")
```

Or you could download it and install it manually from [this](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-04-12/web/packages/rjson/index.html) mran snapshot.

Comment: I have to use 3.6.3 version, I don't have a chance to change it.

Comment: Answer updated with possible workarounds.

Comment: remotes option work for me! I had 3.6.3 version